# How can I get VMAC Code in pure c?

Tags: algorithm-design, mac

I had find a paper about VMAC algorithm:[VMAC: Message Authentication Code using Universal Hashing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-krovetz-vmac-00).

Now I want to implement this algorithm, But i don't find test vectors about it.

Who can give some advise? Where can i find it's code ?

Comment: Did you see the appendix? https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-krovetz-vmac-00#section-7

Comment: Can you give me code about c language?

Comment: Hmm. Do you want to code it yourself or not? Test vectors are inputs, outputs, and maybe some internals. Sorry, Crypto.SE is not related to coding serve

Comment: I have decided against closing this question because it asks for test vectors, a question which is very much on-topic for Crypto.SE. However requests for non-trivial implementations are off-topic across the entirety of SE (except for library requests with that implementation which are for [softwarerecs.se]). I'll leave it to answerers to optionally link to an implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMAC was a joint work by Wei Dai and Ted Krovetz. It so happens that Wei Dai at that time was also actively working on his own cryptographic library ([Crypto++](https://cryptopp.com/)), which of course also includes VMAC.

You can find the test vectors [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/TestVectors/vmac.txt) and the optimized implementation [here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/vmac.cpp).

Two examples for VMAC-AES-128 are:

```
Key: "abcdefghijklmnop"
IV: "bcdefghi"

Message: ""
MAC: 472766C70F74ED23481D6D7DE4E80DAC
Message: "abc"
MAC: 4EE815A06A1D71EDD36FC75D51188A42
```